# Finding the value of `TIME_WAIT`

Tags: port, tcp

How does one determine the value of `TIME_WAIT` for port reuse? I am running a non-persistent HTTP load generator on a client box and need to find this value on the client.

I see `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout` being mentioned, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46066357/7154924) suggests this is not the right parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Massive dupes but here is the answer:

You look at the source code. [include/net/tcp.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/net/tcp.h#L120)

```
#define TCP_TIMEWAIT_LEN (60*HZ) /* how long to wait to destroy TIME-WAIT
                  * state, about 60 seconds */
```

You change this value by editing this file and recompiling the kernel.

Comment: At first I thought HZ was Hertz; the variable naming seems rather misleading...